# Hide/Show FloatingActionButton on tab Click

Tags: android, layout, material-design, floating-action-button, android-tablayout

I have a SlidingTabLayout with this pageListener, when I scroll to another tab, the FAB hides and then shows again, this is correct, the problem is that it doesn't work when I click tab, it just hides and doesn't reappear until I scrollPage again. Any ideas? (I'm using support design library of course)

```
private ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener pageListener = new        
ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener() {

    @Override
    public void onPageSelected(int arg0) {
        Log.i("SCROLL", "onPageSelected");
        fab.show()
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrolled(int arg0, float arg1, int arg2) {
        Log.i("SCROLL", "onPageScrolled");
        if(fab.isShown()) {
            fab.hide();
        }
    }

    @Override
    public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int arg0) {
        Log.i("SCROLL", "onStateChanged: "+arg0);
        fab.show();

    }
};
```

Comment: are you using tablayout provided in design support library?

Comment: if yes,then may be you might have missed this line `tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);`

Comment: I'm using this SlidingTabLayout.

https://developer.android.com/intl/es/samples/SlidingTabsBasic/src/com.example.android.common/view/SlidingTabLayout.html

Comment: Then have you implemented tabclicklistener like shown in the developer docs[see at the bottom of the page]?

Comment: Yes, I have the same code, copied and pasted. It changes the fragment when I click the tab, but it doesn't show the FAB.

Comment: @Droidwala after testing again, I realized that it sometimes show it and sometimes not. May it be a problem with the onPageListener?